# RoR - ActiveAdmin with ckEditor shows html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, activeadmin

Hi to the helper on this ..

I have looked constantly everywhere to get this to work but no success.

Setup:
- ActiveAdmin with ckEditor for articles (blog post)

Issue:
- I can input text and images in the body for the ckeditor, but when I go to the articles.html page it spits out all the html tags and source code.

Article.rb (under active admin)

permit_params :title, :banner, :article_icon, :introduction, :body,

```
:section
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs do
      input :title
      input :banner, :required => true, :as => :file
      input :article_icon, :required => true, :as => :file
      input :introduction
      input :body, :as => :ckeditor
      input :section, as: :select, collection:Article.sections.keys
      # input :format_text
    end
    actions
  end
```

development.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```

initializer for active_admin.rb

```
config.register_javascript 'ckeditor/init.js'
```

gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin_ckeditor'
```

Article.html

```
  <% article_id = "article-id-#{article.id}" %>
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="<%= article_id %>" />
            <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target"><%= article.body %></span></p>
            <label for="<%= article_id %>" class="read-more-trigger"></label>

        </div>
```

(the article.body should be shown without tags)
I have also uploaded an image and here is what shown.

```
<p>body content goes here<img alt="" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1/content_proportionspace_fabioaraujo.jpg" style="width: 800px; height: 450px;" /></p>
```

- How do I get to remove this so it displays without tags and src for images?
- Also tried rake pre-compile (but my public/cdkeditor_assets only has one subfolder for picture) shouldn't there be more folders and assets?

Hope someone can help.
Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora - what does that mean. the .html_safe works , although it breaks the view more and view less action.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora - the file is already name articles.html.erb, all my html are .erb files

Comment: Yes this works and displays everything, although it creates a new issue regarding the div action - which the body is hidden unless user clicks on 'view more'. Using the raw / safe mode removes the div action of 'read more state' and displays the full content

Comment: This tags works well in rails 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137108/discussion-between-bernard-biggs-and-harleen-kaur-arora).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.html_safe` to render the html tags

```
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="<%= article_id %>" />
        <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target"><%= article.body.html_safe %></span></p>
        <label for="<%= article_id %>" class="read-more-trigger"></label>

    </div>
```

Image thing, I don't know.

Comment: this works perfectly .html_safe and further also renders the images but this further breaks the trigger actions of the content ... i normally have a button to view more - but with the .html_safe this just leaves the container open

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by using js for button class actions instead of inline html and css actions for 'read-more-state'.

Content displays correctly with the html_safe with the open and close content hidden depending on button state